# how do I extract substring (group) using regex without knowing if regex matches?

Tags: regex, scala

I want to use this

```
val r = """^myprefix:(.*)""".r
val r(suffix) = line
println(suffix)
```

But it gives an error when the string doesn't match. How do I use a similar construct where matching is optional?

Edit: To make it clear, I need the group `(.*)`

Comment: So, what should be return when the regex does not match, an empty string?

Comment: I don't care, as long as the program doesn't exit... Also an if "contains" or similar would be fine, it just has to be short and elegant.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can extract match groups via pattern matching.

```
val r = """^myprefix:(.*)""".r
line match {
  case r(group) => group
  case _ => ""
}
```

Another way using `Option`:

```
Option(line) collect { case r(group) => group }
```

Comment: I just tried this, and the val name does not need to be uppercase (at least on scala 2.9.2 on windows)

Comment: Oh right, only without the match group it would be necessary.

Comment: What's the underlying sytax here? Why does

Answer (score 27):

```
"""^myprefix:(.*)""".r        // Regex
  .findFirstMatchIn(line)     // Option[Match]
  .map(_ group 1)             // Option[String]
```

This has the advantage that you can write it as a one-liner without needing to assign the regex to an intermediate value `r`.

In case you're wondering, group 0 is the matched string while group 1 etc are the capture groups.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
r.findFirstIn(line)
```

UPD:

```
scala> val rgx = """^myprefix:(.*)""".r
rgx: scala.util.matching.Regex = ^myprefix:(.*)

scala> val line = "myprefix:value"
line: java.lang.String = myprefix:value

scala> for (rgx(group) <- rgx.findFirstIn(line)) yield group
res0: Option[String] = Some(value)
```

Comment: But it returns the whole match and I want the group (in my case, the suffix)

Comment: I could use it this way       if (!r.findFirstIn(line).isEmpty) {
       val r(suffix) = line
       println(suffix)
      } but that looks strange...